# Expressing a decimal as a fraction in lowest terms

Tags: output-formatting, arithmetic

How can I express a decimal such as 0.1845095405274387 as a fraction in its lowest terms?

Comment: `Rationalize[0.1845095405274387, 10^-50]` ?

Answer (score 9):

Another option:

```
RootApproximant[0.1845095405274387, 1]
```

Answer (score 8):

Still another possibility:

```
Last[Convergents[0.1845095405274387]]
```

Comment: +1 for referencing a non-esoteric function I cannot recall using.

Comment: I deal with continued fractions somewhat frequently, you see...

Answer (score 7):

A couple of bits of code for your consideration:

```
FromDigits@#/10^(Length@# - #2) & @@ RealDigits[0.1845095405274387]

Rationalize[0.1845095405274387, $MachineEpsilon]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard...I Thank you