# How to get rid of 0. (zero dot) without get rid of small number?

Tags: numerics

I am trying to get rid of terms with 0., $x+0.I$ for example.

I've found this question: [A dot appearing after a zero, and making the entries of a matrix into fractions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/a-dot-appearing-after-a-zero-and-making-the-entries-of-a-matrix-into-fractions) and the solution is using `Chop`.

However, some terms that I want to keep are very small, $10^{-14}$, and also neglect with `Chop` too.

As I looked on the internet, I can't find the solution for this question. If it is duplicate, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Would the 2-argument form of [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) suit your needs?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of imaginary parts or am I misinterpreting? If so, you can use `Re`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans The answer is yes. However, I am stuck with the problem that `Re` gives me Re(...). Then, I use `Refine` but imaginary parts still exists, Re(n1+n2*I)x y. Finally, I use `Conjugate` to get rid of imaginary parts and then I get this problem.

Comment: @JasonB. I admitted that I just know that I can use 2-argument form of `Chop`. It's my mistake. However, @mikado's answer can solve this problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rationalize` works for the example you give.

```
x + 0. I
(* (0. + 0. I) + x *)

Rationalize[%]
(* x *)
```