# How to tick the intersection with x axis automatically?

Tags: plotting, functions, functional-style

I am plotting a simple sinusoidal function as below. Is there a way to tick the intersection of the function and x axis automatically on the plot?

```
Plot[Sin[2*Pi*t - Pi/3], {t, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[Sin[2*Pi*t - Pi/3], {t, -1.5, 1.5}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.03]]]
```

[image]

---

If you really want to display on the plot only the `Ticks` at the intersections, not just highlight the points, then you can extract the points from `plot`:

```
ticks = SetAccuracy[#, 4]& @ Cases[Normal[plot], Point[x_] :> x[[1]], Infinity]

Plot[Sin[2*Pi*t - Pi/3], {t, -1.5, 1.5}, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}]
```

[image]

---

The `Mesh` approach is more likely to grasp all the intersections for more complicated functions, where `FindInstance`, `NSolve`, `FindRoot` etc. may fail in finding all solutions.

---

Why `SetAccuracy`? Because

```
a = Cases[Normal[plot], Point[x_] :> x[[1]], Infinity]
```

gives

> {-1.33346, -0.833429, -0.333212, 0.166831, 0.666733, 1.16661}

which are correct to three, sometimes four, decimal places; it would require some way of *rounding* to be expressed in simple fractions (see [Can Mathematica propose an exact value based on an approximate one?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16/can-mathematica-propose-an-exact-value-based-on-an-approximate-one) and [Expressing a decimal as a fraction in lowest terms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7086/expressing-a-decimal-as-a-fraction-in-lowest-terms)). In this particular case, `Rationalize` does a good job:

```
ticks = Rationalize[#, 10^-3]& @ a
```

> {-4/3, -5/6, -1/3, 1/6, 2/3, 7/6}

Then

```
Plot[Sin[2*Pi*t - Pi/3], {t, -1.5, 1.5}, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}]
```

[image]

**Note:** the locations of the tick labels aren't very fortunate in this case. Relocating them might be possible by adapting these approaches:

- [Is it possible to position ticklabels on the negative y axis on its right side?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6399/22013)
- [Labels and tickmarks inside Frame](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2608/22013)

Answer (score 3):

First define your function, and use `FindInstance` to create a function for finding the tick positions:

```
f[t_]:=Sin[2*Pi*t - Pi/3];
ticks[lo_,hi_,n_:7]:=t /. N@FindInstance[Sin[2*Pi*t - Pi/3] == 0 && lo < t < hi, {t},Reals, n];

Plot[f[t],{t,-1.5,1.5},Ticks->{ticks[-1.5,1.5],Automatic}]
```

You might have to play with `n` depending on your plot. I also assume your axis is always going to be at `y=0`, which you could add as an additional parameter if you wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To choose a different appearance.

```
f[t_] = Sin[2*π*t - π/3];
sol = t /. Solve[{f[t] == 0, -π/2 < t < π/2}, t];

Plot[f[t], {t, -3/2, 3/2}, Ticks -> {Range[-π/2, π/2, π/4], Range[-1, 1, 0.5]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
Epilog -> {Arrow[{{#, 0.25}, {#, 0}}] & /@ sol, Text[#, {#, 1/2}] & /@ sol}]
```

[image]